# How to calculate width, height and position of bezier curve

Tags: position, height, width, curve, bezier

I have a bezier curve defined by start point, end point and 2 control points (parameters of this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp).
First, I need to calculate width and height of this curve. If I make rectangle around a curve, its width and height is what I need.
Then I need to start point (x,y of left top corner) of this rectangle.

How can I calculate that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For true bounds, you need to compute the extremities of the curve's component functions, then plug those into the bezier function for the (x,y) coordinates for each extremity. I cover this over at http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#extremities, which also explains how to do most of the steps required to get there in the text leading up to the extremities section. paragraphs 11 and 12/13 then cover bounding boxes (plain, which you're probably interested in, and tight, respectively)

Answer (score 1):

I found approximate solution in some other topic (I don't remember which one) but here is simple JS function to calculate it:

```
function getCurveBoundary(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy) {
        var tobx = bx - ax;
        var toby = by - ay;
        var tocx = cx - bx;
        var tocy = cy - by;
        var todx = dx - cx;
        var tody = dy - cy;
        var step = 1 / 40;    // precission
        var d, px, py, qx, qy, rx, ry, tx, ty, sx, sy, x, y, i, minx, miny, maxx, maxy;
        function min(num1, num2) {
            if (num1 > num2)
                return num2;
            if (num1 < num2)
                return num1;
            return num1;
        }
        function max(num1, num2) {
            if (num1 > num2)
                return num1;
            if (num1 < num2)
                return num2;
            return num1;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 41; i++)
        {
            d = i * step;
            px = ax + d * tobx;
            py = ay + d * toby;
            qx = bx + d * tocx;
            qy = by + d * tocy;
            rx = cx + d * todx;
            ry = cy + d * tody;
            toqx = qx - px;
            toqy = qy - py;
            torx = rx - qx;
            tory = ry - qy;

            sx = px + d * toqx;
            sy = py + d * toqy;
            tx = qx + d * torx;
            ty = qy + d * tory;
            totx = tx - sx;
            toty = ty - sy;

            x = sx + d * totx;
            y = sy + d * toty;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                minx = x;
                miny = y;
                maxx = x;
                maxy = y;
            }
            else
            {
                minx = min(minx, x);
                miny = min(miny, y);
                maxx = max(maxx, x);
                maxy = max(maxy, y);
            }
        }
        return {x: Math.round(minx), y: Math.round(miny), width: Math.round(maxx - minx), height: Math.round(maxy - miny)};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an approximate solution, it's pretty easy to compute a solution that's always big enough to cover the curve, but might be too big.

Beziers satisfy the 'convex hull property' which means that you can take a bounding box of your control points and that will bound the curve itself.

If you're looking for something more accurate, then the simplest way is to evaluate a bunch of different points on the curve and take the bounding box of those points on the curve.  You can vary the number of points you test in order to change the quality/speed tradeoff.

If you're looking for something that directly computes the exact answer then what you need is a root finder to look for extrema of the functions x(t) and y(t).